Central logout behavior when upgrading to pac4j v5
Previously I had a filter configured like
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Bean
public LogoutFilter pac4jCentralLogoutFilter() {
    LogoutFilter f = new LogoutFilter();

    f.setConfig(pac4jDefaultConfig());
    f.setDefaultUrl("/login?logout");
    f.setLocalLogout(true);
    f.setCentralLogout(true);
    f.setSuffix("logout");
    f.setLogoutLogic(myLogoutLogic());
    
    return f;
}

And this all worked to log me out either locally or from the remote IDP.
I see in the release notes
`5) SAML SLO
Up to v5, when a central logout was triggered for the SAML protocol, a local logout was performed as well. This is no longer the case in v5 to be consistent with the CAS and OpenID Connect protocols.
The local logout should be triggered by a logout request from the IdP (received on the callback endpoint) or explicitly by enabling the local logout.`
This suggest something has changed for SAML but I can't find where to do the equivalent of the above filter in the new v5 code. All these methods have gone away. Please advise.
I expected it to work like before but I can't find the mechanism to do it.

I don't see any calls to LogoutLogic.perform in the codebase so although i see something about central logout in there I assume it's not getting called but standard logout logic.

It means that you must explicitly define: f.setLocalLogout(true); to perfom a local logout (before the central logout) or you must be sure that the central logout at the IdP will send a logout request to the application (to perform a local logout).
